# I want access of a property of my class in a static metod, how can i do? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, static, this

I have this code:

```
class Animal{

   surname="pluto"

   static test(){console.log("test "+this.surname)};
}

Animal.test()
```

I have Undefine why??

I can use "this" in a static method?

Thanks

Comment: `this` refers to `Animal`, which does not have a `surname` property

Comment: sorry? surname="pluto".... is inside the class

Comment: It's not a property of the class. It runs inside the constructor, assigning an *instance* that property.

Comment: ok ... but I not have a costructor... If I wold have write Calss Animal{ constructor(){this.surname="pippo"} .... thet is costructor ... isn't it? so in this case I undestund that I have to use a istance... but if I want access of a property of my class as 0 surname  is in my questin... how can I do?

Comment: `surname="pluto"` is class field syntax - it'll run inside the constructor, even if you don't have an explicit `constructor` method

Comment: try this: class Animal{

   surname="pluto"

   test(){console.log("test "+this.surname)};
}

new Animal().test()

Comment: ok perfect... so new question  if I want access of a property of my class in a static metod, how can i do? is it possible?

Comment: its not possible in static. because atatic means not related to a context

Comment: ok perfect thanks !!!!

Comment: even if you will define surname in constructor , it sitill will not be available in the static method as the constructor will be invoked when you create an object of class.
what you can do is define the variable outside the class and access it in static method, or use a static getter method for the variable.

Comment: You have to define the property as `static` as well, which off the top of my head isn't supported in standard Javascript (Typescript or such have syntax for it). You can do `Animal.surname = ...` after the fact for the same effect.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you all.